# How to resolve TF10175 Error When Branching

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I have a project I would like to branch.

So I follow the typical steps:

1. Open Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio.
2. Right click on the Branch that I want to Branch.
3. Open the Branch dialog.
4. Accept the default "Target Branch Name"
5. Click Branch.

I then get the error message:
"The Project xyz team project does not exist."

So I then went online source control and create new root project manually.

I then select it in the Branch Dialog and click "Branch"

I then get the error message: The Item $/xyz already exists.

How do I resolve this?

it's not creating a new branch, nor letting me selecting an existing branch.

Greg

Answer (score 1):

I am going to post my own answer here I found after quite a bit of work.

The problem is with the folder structure: My Project structure was too flat, like this:

```
Root Team Folder
   --- Solution Folder 
      --- Project 1
      --- Project 2
```

Instead of:

```
Root Team Folder
   --- Main Branch Folder
      --- Solution Folder
        --- Project 1
        --- Project 2
```

You can now Branch the "Main Branch Folder"

and it will look like this:

```
Root Team Folder
   --- Main Branch Folder
      --- Solution Folder
        --- Project 1
        --- Project 2
   --- Dev Branch Folder
      --- Solution Folder
        --- Project 1
        --- Project 2
```

The flat structure works until you try to branch it, and then TFS will not let you branch a root folder.

Branched Folders are at the same level as the Source Branch folder.